# Foundation 6 - Override default typography with custom fonts

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

How do I over ride the default typography font in foundation 6?

I am using foundation-cli and I dont want to change the sass files generated but over ride them with the new styles.

Best practices on this? Suggestions?

Thanks
Derek

Comment: You may have to edit the `_settings.scss` file, that's it's very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, edit **_settings.scss**.  Look for this line ...

```
$body-font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Even create another memory variable for Headings, if you like ...

```
$heading-font: 'Droid Serif', serif;
```

Comment: How do you do this without sass? Is it possible to do it just with css ?